# What does "new" use when a runtime library is not used?

Tags: c++

In C for example, there is no malloc() without a runtime library (libc). And I think for example, on Windows malloc just calls HeapAlloc(). But in C++, the way to allocate dynamic memory is actually a keyword of the language; same for "delete". So therefore, how would "new" work if you compiled your code without a runtime library?

Thanks

Comment: `librarly` made me chuckle :) - But why won't you want to use a library

Comment: I don't not want to, I'm just curious how absolutely native C++ would work since it is a language keyword

Comment: I don't understand your question. "bool" is also a language keyword, yet do you think it stops working in "absolutely native" C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If new operator is not overloaded, it is generally the same as malloc function. **It is platform dependent**. The only difference, is that it automatically manage the initialization of the data.

EDIT:

On linux you can not compile without standard library. You got the following message:

```
phong@colinux ~ $ g++ -nostdlib test.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000080480d8
/tmp/ccOV36hW.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccOV36hW.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: So C can run with absolutely nothing, but C++ needs a runtime library if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Milo: Not quite.  The precise answer to that is *implementation defined*, but in most cases, certain features (that vary by implementation) are provided in a library, others by the compiler.  Dynamic memory allocation is almost always defined in a library, because it is very useful to substitute different allocators at link time for different purposes.  If you stay away from those features, and are using a compiler that doesn't freak out about that, then you won't have any problems.

Comment: my mistake, on linux if it can not compile without standard library. But the good news is that you can still overload new operator. As TokenMacGuy said, it depend of the platform.

Comment: It is certainly possible to implement all variants of operator new and delete, as well as functions such as __gxx_personality_v0 (and a few others for virtual methods and such) and compile C++ without any additional libraries. C++ operating system kernels exist without libraries by implementing this support directly.

Answer (score 0):

Like any function pointer not found.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic memory allocation (as is also `printf()`) requires OS support. You cannot write a hardware (or OS) independent versions of these functions.

A program without any OS support (as you expect from C) won't be able to interact with the outside, so it's useless.

This means that this pure theoretical question has no sense.

@In silico: This is a hard one.. On a controller, you have to know some details about the particular hardware you run, so that you know that `*(char*)(0x123)^=1` will toggle a led. It's not something defined in C standard, but your knowledge about outside. The OS is nothing else than a collection of knowledge about the hardware.
Sure, you could run without CRT (as some viruses do), by finding the kernel address in memory and looking for exported functions. But again, it just reproduce the function of CRT that is simly vital to any program.

@Fred Nurk: What I wanted to say is that "pure C" does not define any standard mean to interact with the hardware, it is something done by OS. So there is no point of running such program. For example, you could not write a "generic" `malloc` that would run on every system.

@Phong: yes, and this would mean that you've just written the CRT (or OS) for it. And it won't be portable as is the "pure C" itself.

**NOTE:** by **OS support** I also mean the knowledge about the particular hardware
By **pure C** I mean portable code that uses only standard C constructs.

Comment: "A program without any OS support... won't be able to interact with the outside." - How would you explain the software that runs on microcontrollers (which are capable of interacting with the outside), that typically do not have operating systems?

Comment: On such a microcontroller, your software runs as though it is the operating system.  You would have direct access to memory so a load/store of address X would actually refer to address X.  If you want dynamic memory functionality, you would have to write it yourself.

Comment: Isn't this answer a tautology? It seems to define both stdout (rather than the formatting aspect of printf, I hope) and heap allocation (rather than management, I hope) as OS features, then says you need an OS to use OS features.

Comment: You can implement yourself a printf function for a microcontroller. It will run as a library respecting the Standard library but there may be NO OS! Your image of toggling a led is too simple. If you for example write function printf which will display activate led/pixel/lcd by using a hardware to display printf message. You can do it, and `with no OS`.